REACT-VITE-DOCKER ERROR: Could not resolve entry module "index.html". error during build: RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "index.html"
Im migrating my existing React-Vite app into a docker container, but I keep getting this error when running the docker build command:
\> vite-project@0.0.0 postinstall > npm run build > vite-project@0.0.0 build > vite build vite v4.5.3 building for production... â 0 modules transformed. â built in 8ms Could not resolve entry module "index.html". error during build: RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "index.html".
This is my Dockerile:
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 5173

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev", "--", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]

This is my .dockerignore
node_modules
dist
jsdoc.json

.gitignore
.vscode
.prettierignore
.prettierrc
.jsconfig.json
.eslintignore
.eslintrc.cjs

And this is my project structure: enter image description here
Any suggestions on what can I do to solve this problem? Im pretty new to docker and all that stuff
